# Multi part upload from web browser to Amazon S3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, plupload

We currently have a small web app, part of which is file uploads. Currently we are using Plupload on the client with chunking enabled to allow large files be uploaded. The files are saved on the app server and the chunks are appended as they come up.

Now we are moving to Amazon S3.
Can any one share few examples on how to upload in file in chunks on s3
I tried using  Presinged url it is uploading  but there is a limit of only 5 gb .

Answer (score 7):

You have to utilize a combination of Multipart uploads & S3 signed URLS.

Basically, the steps is to:

1. Initiate a multipart upload on the backend

```
  const params = {
    Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: OBJECT_NAME
  }

  const res = await s3.createMultipartUpload(params).promise()

  return res.UploadId
```

2. Create pre-signed URLs for each chunk (API level)

```
async function generatePresignedUrlsParts(s3: AWS.S3, uploadId: string, parts: number) {
  const baseParams = {
    Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: OBJECT_NAME,
    UploadId: uploadId
  }

  const promises = []

  for (let index = 0; index < parts; index++) {
    promises.push(
      s3.getSignedUrlPromise('uploadPart', {
      ...baseParams,
      PartNumber: index + 1
    }))
  }

  const res = await Promise.all(promises)

  return res.reduce((map, part, index) => {
    map[index] = part
    return map
  }, {} as Record<number, string>)
}
```

3. Upload each chunk

```
import Axios from 'axios'

interface Part {
  ETag: string
  PartNumber: number
}

const FILE_CHUNK_SIZE = 10_000_000

async function uploadParts(file: Buffer, urls: Record<number, string>) {
  const axios = Axios.create()
  delete axios.defaults.headers.put['Content-Type']

  const keys = Object.keys(urls)
  const promises = []

  for (const indexStr of keys) {
    const index = parseInt(indexStr)
    const start = index * FILE_CHUNK_SIZE
    const end = (index + 1) * FILE_CHUNK_SIZE
    const blob = index < keys.length
      ? file.slice(start, end)
      : file.slice(start)

    promises.push(axios.put(urls[index], blob))
  }

  const resParts = await Promise.all(promises)

  return resParts.map((part, index) => ({
    ETag: (part as any).headers.etag,
    PartNumber: index + 1
  }))
}
```

4. Complete multipart upload

```
interface Part {
  ETag: string
  PartNumber: number
}

async function completeMultiUpload(uploadId: string, parts: Part[]) {
  const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: /* Bucket owner access key id */,
    secretAccessKey: /* Bucket owner secret */,
    sessionToken: `session-${cuid()}`
  })

  const params = {
    Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: OBJECT_NAME,
    UploadId: uploadId,
    MultipartUpload: { Parts: parts }
  }

  await s3.completeMultipartUpload(params).promise()
}
```